# Add class to biggest value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this thing.

**In order to work you need to change the select.**

After you change the option, some values will show, I'm adding the class highest on the biggest value of the `currentDATA[year]`.

But the thing is if I switch to `Something #2` and back to `Something #1`, the correct values are not highlighted.

```
if(value > prevVal) {
    $el.parent().find('span').removeClass('highest');
    $el.addClass('highest');          
}
```

[**Full demo**](http://jsbin.com/fodabajuje/edit?html,js,output)

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prevVal was always zero. So setting that gets it working for one of the years.

Next, you need to reset prevVal to zero for each year so each will find it's own largest value.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

var currentDATA = myJSON[$(this).val()];

for(var year in currentDATA){
  var prevVal = 0;
  console.log(year);
  for(var val in currentDATA[year]) {

    var value = currentDATA[year][val];
    var $el = $('.' + val + '_' + year);

    $el.html(value);

    if(value > prevVal) {
      prevVal = value;
      $el.parent().find('span').removeClass('highest');
      $el.addClass('highest');

    }

  }
}


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must keep tracking the highest value :

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

    var currentDATA = myJSON[$(this).val()];
    var highestVal = 0;
    var highestValObj;

    for(var year in currentDATA){

      for(var val in currentDATA[year]) {

        var value = currentDATA[year][val];
        var $el = $('.' + val + '_' + year);

        $el.html(value);

        if(value > highestVal) {
          highestVal = value;
          highestValObj = $el;

        }

      }
    }

         $('.highest').removeClass('highest');
          highestValObj.addClass('highest');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yor `prevVal` is always 0. Change to if you want your code to work:

```
if(value > prevVal) {
    prevVal = value;
    $el.parent().find('span').removeClass('highest');
    $el.addClass('highest');
}
```

But I would advice you to change prevVal name. The logic is built so that you should not compare current value with previous value, you should compare it with the highest value among all previous values.